# How to add a column for equality of MapType in Spark withColumn?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two columns with type `Map[String, Integer]`, I want to use `withColumn` to add a column to represent equality of the two maps.

I try `df.withColumn("euqal", col("A") === col("B"))`, it throws exception `EqualTo does not support ordering on type map<string,int>`

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using UDF:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//UDF
 val mapEqual = udf((col1: Map[StringType, IntegerType], col2: Map[StringType, IntegerType]) => {
    col1.sameElements(col2)
})

//sample DF
 var df = List((Map("1" -> 1), Map("1" -> 1)), (Map("2" -> 1), Map("2" -> 10)))
        .toDF("col1", "col2")
 df.withColumn("equal", mapEqual('col1, 'col2)).show(false)
 
 +--------+---------+-----+
 |col1    |col2     |equal|
 +--------+---------+-----+
 |[1 -> 1]|[1 -> 1] |true |
 |[2 -> 1]|[2 -> 10]|false|
 +--------+---------+-----+
```